# Hint for computing the mean and variance of $\hat{\alpha} = - \frac{n}{\log \prod_{i=1}^n X_i }$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, variance, means, maximum-likelihood

In my statistical class, we are learning MLE. Last week we end up computing the MLE of parameter $\alpha$ for a random sample $X_1, X_2,...,X_n$ with $\text{Beta}(\alpha,1)$ distribution with support $0<x<1$.

The MLE we found is:

$\hat{\alpha} = - \frac{n}{\log \prod_{i=1}^n X_i }$

Now, I'm trying to compute the mean and variance of this estimator, but have had a hard time trying to figure out how to compute them. The main difficulty comes from having the random variable X_i in the denominator.

Any hint I can consider to get through?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Find the distribution of each $-\log X_k$, then the distribution of $T_n=-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\log X_k$. These are simple. Then use $$E(\hat\alpha_n)=n\int_0^\infty\frac1tf_{T_n}(t)dt$$